# Tool to draw transparent icon for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, graphics

Is there a handy tool to draw transparent icons for an iPhone app?

I know PhotoShop can do this, but I prefer a simple one.

Comment: Which OS do you use? Mac OS X

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but one about design software, so it belongs on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pixelmator is simple, quite cheap and popular on the Mac.

I find it too simple and prefer Gimp, which is nowhere near as simple to use, but is very powerful and free.

Comment: Now, It comes in price. :( 30$ .

Comment: @sugar: AFAIK, it has always had a price tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for free image editors, I recommand you to follow this link.

[Link to free image editors question ( Super User )](https://superuser.com/questions/26105/free-image-editors-for-mac-os-x-closed)

It was an question asked by me & there were many good answers for mac image editors.

you might choose any of them.